# use one uniform random variable to simulate another?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, simulation

I ws given a question:
Use 1000 simulations of uniform random variable U[0,1] to simulate 1000 simulations of another uniform random variable U[-3,7], how can I do that in Excel using rand() command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\sim U([0,1])$, it follows that $10X-3\sim U([-3,7])$.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but U[-3,7] is a special case as you can minus -3 on both sides, what should I do if I want to simulate U[-3,6]?

Comment: You can always use the same "trick". If you want to simulate $U([-3,6])$, just consider $9X-3$. In general, if you want to simulate $U([a,b])$, consider $(b-a)X+a$.